# Core Data Select Induvidual Fields

Tags: objective-c

I have a core data model with the following info:

**Entity:** CourseSubjects
**Attributes:**
-account_id
-course_code
-course_id
-name

I need to be able to select **Only one** piece of data from that database which has the field course_id matching what I want. How would I be able to select only one field from this database which has the course_id?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Your question hints that you have tried nothing and you want someone to write the code for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read "Introduction to Predicates Programming Guide" and the NSPredicate documentation.   In short, you'll create a predicate for course_id and then execute a fetch using that predicate.